# How to project MODIS blue marble image?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have combined MODIS blue marble images into a mosaic, a screen shot of the mosaic raster image with its source info opened in ArcMap is attached. The  file source shows that it has angular coordinates defined. I tried to define projection/project but nothing seems to be working. My problem is that this image does not align with other layers having projections defined (e.g. basemap). So I need to align it with other global maps (e.g. basemap) so that it overlaps with them. I know the coordinates of all the four corners of the map (e.g. bottom left corner is -180, -90 or 180W, 90S). I thought it should be a simple problem of georeferencing but it does not seem so after searching all the information online. How can I project or georeference this image in a simple way using the tools in ArcGIS? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to align your raster layer by coordinates or several known points, you can find the georeferencing toolbar in arcgis Desktop ([online help here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-toolbar-tools.htm)).
I had already test that to put a none spatial picture (like old urban plan) on basemap.
I hope i helped you...

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I georeferenced it using georeferencing tool. I used the four corner coordinates as the control points. I used:
WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000 Projected Bounds: -20037508.3428, -10018754.1714, 20037508.3428, 10018754.1714

Found from here http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-plate-carree/